# OpenGL point sprites not always rendered front to back

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I'm working on a game engine with LWJGL3 in which all objects are point sprites. It uses an orthographic camera and I wrote a vertex shader that calculates the 3D position of each sprite (which also causes the fish-eye lens effect). I calculate the distance to the camera and use that value as the depth value for each point sprite. The data for these sprites is stored in chunks of 16x16 in VBOs.

The issue that I'm having is that the sprites are not always rendered front to back. When looking away from the origin, the depth testing works as intended, but when looking in the direction of the origin, sprites are rendered from back to front which causes a big performance drop.

This might seem like depth testing is not enabled, but when I disable depth testing, sprites in the back are drawn on top of the ones in front, so that is not the case.

Here's the full vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

uniform mat4 camRotMat;     // Virtual camera rotation
uniform vec3 camPos;        // Virtual camera position
uniform vec2 fov;           // Virtual camera field of view
uniform vec2 screen;        // Screen size (pixels)

in vec3 pos;
out vec4 vColor;

void main() {
    // Compute distance and rotated delta position to camera
    float dist = distance(pos, camPos);
    vec3 dXYZ  = (camRotMat * vec4(camPos - pos, 0)).xyz;       

    // Compute angles of this 3D position relative center of camera FOV
    //     Distance is never negative, so negate it manually when behind camera
    vec2 rla = vec2(atan(dXYZ.x, length(dXYZ.yz)),
                    atan(dXYZ.z, length(dXYZ.xy) * sign(-dXYZ.y)));

    // Find sprite size and coordinates of the center on the screen
    float size = screen.y / dist * 2;                           // Sprites become smaller based on their distance
    vec2 px = -rla / fov * 2;                                   // Find pixel position on screen of this object

    // Output
    vColor =  vec4((1 - (dist * dist) / (64 * 64)) + 0.5);      // Brightness
    gl_Position = vec4(px, dist / 1000, 1.0);                   // Position on the screen
    gl_PointSize = size;                                        // Sprite size
}
```

In the first image, you can see how the game normally looks. In the second one, I've disabled alpha-testing, so you can see sprites are rendered front to back. But in the third image, when looking in the direction of the origin, sprites are being drawn back to front.

---

Edit:
I am almost 100% certain the depth value is set correctly. The size of the sprites is directly linked to the distance, and they resize correctly when moving around. I also set the color to be brighter when the distance is lower, which works as expected.

I also set the following flags (and ofcourse clear the frame and depth buffer):

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL);
```

Edit2:
Here's a gif of what it looks like when you rotate around: https://i.imgur.com/v4iWe9p.gifv

Edit3: 
I think I misunderstood how depth testing works. Here is a video of how the sprites are drawn over time: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgORzkM9U2w
That explains the initial problem, so now I just need to find a way to render them in a different order depending on the camera rotation.

[image: example]

Comment: It seems to me like the 3rd image can be the expected if you have been calculating the distances from the origin, not from the camera. If `pos` is in eye space, I'd expect the distance to be simply `-pos`. Can you show us more of the vertex shader?

Comment: I'm not using the usual perspective camera, but I'm calculating the angles myself. I've added the full code now

Comment: To clarify: I don't think that's the case, `pos` is the world-position of the vertex, but it's used to calculate the pixel on the screen where the center of the sprite should be

Comment: Just a guess: In `vec4(px, dist / 1000, 1.0);`, perhaps `dist` is being cast to `int` and you end up with 0 all the time.

Comment: Hmm good catch, but it made no apparant changes. I think the problem lies in the fact that the sprites are rendered to the depth buffer in the order that the rendering is done. I did some further research into early z-testing, which should be working if you have alpha testing disabled, but it doesn't for some reason. In any case, the performance issue should be mostly resolved when I implement rendering via a quad/octree